# Считывание информации о месте прикосновения к емкостному дисплею

Tags: android

Для мобильных устройств мне необходимо разработать приложение, считывающее изменение емкости при прикосновении к сенсорному экрану. Чтобы можно было различить двух разных пользователей. Такое возможно (и как) или такой низкоуровневый доступ для программистов закрыт?

Comment: Это учебное задание или личный проект? На одном устройстве или на разных?

Comment: Мысль сделать личный проект. В идеале должно быть и под Android и под iOS.

Comment: Т.е. и на разных устройствах, и на разных платформах, если такое возможно.

Comment: как емкость нажатия может различить двух разных людей? Что-то вы не правильно свое задание излагаете. Кстати какого вида сенсор? В заголовке один вопрос, а здесь совершенно другой, что-то здесь не так.

Comment: По прикосновению к экрану нельзя сколько-нибудь приемлемо точно идентифицировать человека

Comment: @pavlofff, ошибаетесь http://www.engadget.com/2016/01/15/googles-creepy-plan-to-kill-the-password/

Comment: @Oceinic наберитесь решимости прочитать и осмыслить, что написано по вашей ссылке и что написал я.

Answer (score 4):

Одного прикосновения может оказаться достаточно только если в смартфоне есть  встроенный сканнер отпечатка пальца. В остальных случаях собираются данные о поведении пользователя за длительное время и анализируются алгоритмами Исскуственного Интеллекта (Artificial Intelligence).
Чтобы самостоятельно реализовать что-то подобное, вам понадобится как минимум знание Теории Вероятностей (Probability Theory) и алгоритмов Машинного Обучения (Machine Learning)